# How to count number of parameter expansions, arithmetic expansions etc?

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm new to bash scripting.

Trying to write a simple script which reads from standard input (file) and writes to standard output. I want the script to count the number of parameter/arithmetic expansions and command substitutions.

For standard input i've done this so far:

```
file=${1--}
while IFS= read -r line; do 
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < <(cat - "$file")
```

Comment: That actually sounds like an ambitious task for a beginner - to do it *right*, you'd essentially need to write a complete shell parser - in the shell.

Comment: I doubt it. I do know how to count lines in a bash script , I am trying to find a way to count the special characters like $ , () {} in order to complete the requirement of the script.

Comment: Are you doing it just as an exercise or is there a real practical case for doing this I can't imagine?

Comment: @steeldriver Overly ambitious but not impossible. See my answer.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy riiight... but (to play devil's advocate here) what should the count be if I write `echo "\${var%i*} = ${var%i*}"`? is that two parameter substitutions, or a literal string followed by a parameter substitution?

Comment: @steeldriver yeah, good point.  But again that can be excluded,  in `grep`  at least with  `'[^\]${.*}'`.  I mean, yeah, it's ambitions, but regex can do the trick here and there.

Comment: How about stuff like single-quoted strings containing what looks like expansions (`'$foo'`) or backslash-escaped backslashes (`\\$foo`)? ;) I have the feeling that it could be pretty much done with some horrible Perl script, but I hope I'll never need to do it...

Comment: Please don't deface your question only because you got confused or upset with it, or the reaction it caused. There are numerous people who invested time in this and your question is not only for you, but for future readers also. I now have rolled back your edit, to make this again the actual question which has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

## The practical way

Just use `grep` with `-c` flag for counting, or better yet `grep -o '<PATTERN>' | wc -l` (see note about it later in text). Depending on how you want your output to look like and depending on what you want to achieve, there's multiple ways to set it up.

Of course, there's different parameter expansion types,so we'd need to write different patterns for them. Here I just wrote patterns substitution, prefix removal, and arithmetic expansion, but you can adapt them to any other one.

At the very basic level, we can call individual commands as so:

```
$ cat ./myscript.sh                                                         
#!/bin/bash

var="string"
echo "${var/string/thread}"
echo $((2+2))
echo $((3*2))

echo ${var#*i}
echo ${var##*i}

echo ${var%i*}
echo ${var%%i*}
$ grep -c '${.*}' myscript.sh                                               
1
$ grep -c '$((.*))' myscript.sh                                             
2
```

---

And that's just the basic idea. You could put multiple `grep` patterns into a script with nice leading message. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf "\nNumber of arithmetic expansions:"
grep -c '$((.*))' "$1"
printf "\nNumber of substitutions:"
grep -c '${.*\/.*\/.*}' "$1"
printf "\nNumber of prefix removals:"
grep -c '${.*[#]\{1,2\}.*}' "$1"
```

And then call that script like:

```
./count_bash_stuff.sh myscript.sh
```

---

Alternatively, just put all patterns into file and call `grep` with `-f`. Of course, it'll output just the *total count of all matches* not individual ones:

```
$ cat ./patterns                                                            
$((.*))
${.*\/.*\/.*}
${.*[#]\{1,2\}.*}
$ grep -c -f ./patterns ./myscript.sh                                       
5
```

Note: as steeldriver pointed out in the comment below this answer, `grep` is a line matching tool, which means if there's more than one pattern in a line, it will add 1 to count just for that line. Better approach would be to use `-o` flag with `grep` and pipe the output to `wc -l`. Thus, instead we could do something like this for arithmetic expansion:

```
grep -o '$((.*))' |  wc -l
```

---

### The (not so practical)  POSIX shell way

Yes, this is possible. It's tough, but possible with `case` statements. Here I'm just going to write `case` statement for arithmetic expansion and longest prefix removal. The rest is up to reader to adapt and extend.

Again, keep in mind that this is proof of concept. Notice that this uses `/bin/sh` - on Ubuntu this is POSIX-compliant `/bin/dash` shell, not `bash`.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
while IFS="" read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];
do
    case "$line" in
        # arithmetic expansion, appearing anywhere in line
        *'$(('*'))'*) arithmetic_count=$(($arithmetic_count+1));;
        *'${'*##*'}'* ) prefix_count=$((prefix_count+1));;
    esac
done < "$1"

echo "$arithmetic_count"
echo "$prefix_count"
```

And it runs as so:

```
$ ./count_shell_stuff.sh myscript.sh                                                                                                                                   
2
1
```

Why is this not so practical you might ask ? Because writing patterns in `case` can be somewhat challenging, and a bit harder than say in `grep` or `Perl`. Plus, you will have to write `case` for each shell syntax structure. With `grep` or `perl` you could combine multiple patterns into one. But then again, this is just my personal opinion. String pattern matching is still very much possible as I've showed in this little proof of concept, but I wouldn't recommend that as a way to go.

Comment: Note that `grep -c` counts matching *lines* - so will miscount if there is more that a single pattern on a given line. You could try to fix that by using `grep -o` and piping the output of *that* to `wc`, however you will need to make the patterns non-greedy e.g. `grep -Eo '\${[^}]*}' | wc`

Comment: @steeldriver I think you meant `wc -l`, but yeah, good point. I've included that into the answer